# Power normalization step for VLAD vector representation

Tags: matlab, vector, normalization, vlad-vector

I am doing a *Power normalization* step for **VLAD vector** representation `v`. The *un-normalized* VLAD vector for an image in my experiment is of **8192x1** dimension [Considering **128-D SIFT** descriptors, and **K** (centroids) = 64].

Power-law normalization modifies each component as:

```
v_i = sign(v_i) x |v_i|^alpha, i = 1, ..., (k*d)
```

I have written a piece of code to Power-normalize the un-normalized VLAD vector `v`:

```
for i = 1:(k*d)
    v(i) = sign(v(i)) * (abs(v(i)))^alpha;
end
```

`alpha = 0.5`, is a parameter here.

May I know if I am correct with this?
or
I feel on second thought, should `norm` replace `abs`?

Comment: Is this MATLAB code?

Comment: Yes it is MATLAB code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "abs"

Reference: [All about VLAD](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2013/arandjelovic13/arandjelovic13.pdf)

> To obtain the SSR normalized VLAD, each element of an unnormalized
>   VLAD is sign square rooted (i.e. an element x_i is transformed into
>   sign(x_i)*sqrt(|x_i|) )